# How can I connect SSMS to a database saved on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: ssms

I have a database saved on phpMyAdmin with the following information;

[image]

How can I access this from SSMS?
Which parts go where?

[image]

I have tried adding the IP address, username and password but I get an error as shown below.

[image]

Comment: google 'ssms connect mysql' https://www.devart.com/odbc/mysql/docs/microsoft_sql_server_manager_s.htm

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with? The server IP address goes in "Server name", your username goes in "Login" and your password goes in "Password" — without more information about the problems you're having, we have trouble helping you.

Comment: As a bit of clarification, your database is actually in MariaDB; phpMyAdmin is simply a graphical interface to help you manage the database.

Comment: You’ll definitely need to also change the Authentication drop down and possibly also the Server type as well.